# Tell envoyproxy to not override existing cookies

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm using envoyproxy in my application. Envoy is adding a custom header to all incoming requests. If the custom header already exits, envoy with overwrite it with a new value. Is there a way to tell envoy to *not* overwrite this custom header if it already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a dedicated [header append action](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.28.0/api-v3/config/core/v3/base.proto#enum-config-core-v3-headervalueoption-headerappendaction) named `ADD_IF_ABSENT` for this purpose. From the docs:

> ⁣This action will add the header if it doesn’t already exist. If the header already exists then this will be a no-op.

To use it, you will need to add it in the `envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager` filter's `route_config.request_headers_to_add` field. Here's a minimal working filter config below (last line with `append_action` is what you need to set to get the behavior you want):

```yaml
filter_chains:
  - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          http_filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.http.router
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
              - name: local_service
                domains: ["*"]
                routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                    route:
                      cluster: app
            request_headers_to_add:
              - header:
                  key: "x-my-header"
                  value: "set-by-envoy"
                append_action: ADD_IF_ABSENT # this answers your question
```

I've tested it with envoy v1.28.0 and a dummy `app` that just prints the request's `x-my-header` header, and it works perfectly:

```bash
# test 1, don't pass "x-my-header"
curl -s -I localhost:8080 -o /dev/null

# test 2, pass a custom "x-my-header"
curl -s -I -H "x-my-header: set-by-user" localhost:8080 -o /dev/null
```

My application logs shows that first request used the default header set by Envoy, while the second request used the header set when doing the `curl` (so Envoy **have not** overwritten the header thanks to `ADD_IF_ABSENT`):

```
set-by-envoy
[23/Dec/2023 13:35:45] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
set-by-user
[23/Dec/2023 13:35:55] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Note that `append_action` default is `APPEND_IF_EXISTS_OR_ADD` ([in Envoy 1.28.0 at least](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.28.0/api-v3/config/core/v3/base.proto#enum-config-core-v3-headervalueoption-headerappendaction)), so if you don't set its value, the value added in Envoy is appended to the header. Example with the test above:

```
set-by-envoy
[23/Dec/2023 13:40:56] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
set-by-user,set-by-envoy
[23/Dec/2023 13:40:58] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```